# Mobile usability issues reported by Google at Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, crawl-errors, crawl-budget

Google search console reported that some pages have a Mobile Usability issues:

- Clickable elements too close together
- Content wider than screen
- Text too small to read

Some details:

- this is not about restrictions in robots.txt
- some failed pages have less than 8 resources with 550KB size total
- the failed pages make up a small part of the total and are random
- "LIVE TEST" for the same URL may fail randomly
- there is no network problems (packet loss/response time/DNS) with the server where site deployed
- this issue appeared since April 14th
- most of the failed pages have 90-99% mobile performance in PageSpeed Insights or Lighthouse

Lighthouse embedded in the Chrome and [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcolnect.com%2Fen&tab=mobile) haven't found a problem in mobile mode in the same pages that have an issues in Google search console.

But when I use "LIVE TEST" for failed URLs in Google search console, sometimes I get a same failed result with Mobile Usability issues, where CSS file not loaded with a reason "Other error". I think this is an issues reason but I don't understand what can I do to fix it, especially if it is due to some netiquette limitation (crawl budget)